# Django: KeyError at / 'slug'

Tags: django

I'm trying to redirect user to a post according to the slug value. I'm using [django-autoslug](https://pypi.org/project/django-autoslug/) to populate the slug automatically based on the title. I'm trying to capture the slug value in sl variable however I'm getting `KeyError at / 'slug'` error.
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class express_publish(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',unique=True)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body=models.TextField()
    time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views import generic
from .models import *
from .forms import *
def index(request):
    all_publish=express_publish.objects.all()
    form=express_publishForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=express_publishForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        sl=form.cleaned_data['slug']
        return redirect('/'+sl)
    context={'all_publish':all_publish,'form':form}
    return render(request,'publish/index.html',context)

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = express_publish
    template_name = 'publish/post_detail.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the url for the redirect function: currently you're not adding the domain part to the redirect, so Django can't find any url that matches. You need to use 'reverse':

```
from django.urls import reverse

# ...

sl=form.cleaned_data['slug']
url = reverse('post_detail', kwargs={
    'slug': slug
})
return redirect(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reverse()` function.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#examples

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

```py
return redirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[sl]))
```